# Perl Definition for TEXT in an Open Function

Tags: file, perl, text

In Perl, what is the purpose of the capitalize TEXT for the function open? Is it a module or built-in function?

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use v5.10.0;
use warnings;


my $filename = "<file.txt";

open(TEXT, $filename) or die "Can't open file.\n";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TEXT` is what's known as a global file handle. It can be used anywhere, and any time within any code whilst your program is running.

Best practices say to use both the three-argument form of [open()](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), along with a lexical file handle. In the following case, the lexical file handle (`$fh`) is confined to its own scope, and is closed when that scope finishes:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

{
    open my $fh, '<', 'test.txt' or die $!;
    while (<$fh>){
        chomp;
        print "$_\n";
    }
}
```

If you used a global file handle there (`TEXT`), then it would be accessible after the block finished, potentially allowing other parts of code far away to clobber stuff.

Using 3-arg `open` along with lexical file-handles ensures tight confines of your codebase.

Comment: @Minimalist Note that you could still use all CAPS: `open my $TEXT...`, but all caps for Perl variables is kind of a non-enforced way of defining [constant](https://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html) variables